# Define a law for show and read?

Tags: haskell, language-design

The documentation for [`Text.Show`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Text-Show.html) states that this holds for derived instances:

> The result of `show` is a syntactically correct Haskell expression [...]

This fact can be used to pass states of certain computations around as text files or similar objects, because `show` converts the data to a string representation, while `show`'s complement `read` enables continuing the earlier computations.

Of course the above is only possible if `show` and `read` are either derived automatically or implemented appropriately.

Now my question is: **Should the statement from the beginning hold for any `show` function?** Or, more general, **Should a law / laws regarding the behaviour of `read` and `show` be prescribed, similar to `Monad` and `Monoid`?**

A trivial law would be that `(read . show) x == x` must hold for any `x` which is part of `Read` and `Show`.

---

The continuation of this discussion can be found on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2ikmrg/define_laws_for_read_and_show/).

Comment: **My opinion** is that `Show` and `Read` should only ever be derived, except in the circumstances where the constructors are not exported, i.e. `Data.Map.Map`.  In these cases, solutions like `Data.Map.fromList [...]` should be used.  If you want to pretty-print your data or read it from a file, you should make a `pprint` function and a `parse` function, both of which can be implemented however you want.  The use of `Show` and `Read` is very common, but also can lead lots of bugs.  Don't rely on them for anything unless they've been derived.

Comment: @bheklilr That is the essence of this question: Should we make these functions reliable?

Comment: **My opinion** is that `Show` and `Read` should _never_ be relied upon for anything serious. If you want proper serialisation, use a binary library. The only reason to use a textual alternative is for debugging simpler structures; copying and re-using `show` results is only practical for short, manually-editable snippets. If a type isn't able to give a short, readable represantation, but can nevertheless tell _something_ interesting about its contents, it's IMO fine to make a `Show` instance that doesn't conform to this law.

Comment: While I consider this to be a great question to ask and discuss, I feel that the question "Should we make `read . show == show . read == id` a law?" is somewhat subjective and will illicit opinionated responses.  Maybe it would be better served in [/r/haskell](http://reddit.com/r/haskell) or in IRC.

Comment: @bheklilr Alright, I'll close this question but leave it up with a link to reddit as soon as I post it. This aside, I have a problem with ``show . read``. What should ``read 4`` be?

Comment: @ThreeFx Obviously it should be `((show :: a -> String) . (read :: String -> a)) == (x :: a)` for some `(Show a, Read a) => a` in question.  Basically, I'm assuming that they're not polymorphic for this example.  If you're saying that `read . show == id`, then why not `show . read`?

Comment: Not everything showable is also readable and not everything readable is showable.

Comment: @Sofffia This is a prerequisite I did not mention because otherwise it would not make sense.

Comment: the inverse law `show . read = id` need not hold... `read` collapses whitespace and `show` creates fixed whitespace. so it wouldn't apply to something like `Just     Bool`

Comment: *`Just     Bool`... i blame my phone's autocorrect. edit: I guess stack overflow had a problem too. well. imagine it has extra whitespace.

Comment: @JustinL Lots of other examples, think of leading zeros in numbers or escape sequences in strings or order of elements in a set or...

Comment: the laws should be more like this : 
(show . read . show = show) and (read . show . read = read)